# LD pointer not aligned when calling function

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm, mach-o

I am trying to get the following code to assemble and run however I am getting an error from the linker. The error message is:

```
ld: warning: pointer not aligned at address 0x100003FA3 (_main + 7 from print.o)`
ld: unaligned pointer(s) for architecture x86_64
```

This code works on Debian however when I try and compile it on Mac it fails. I get a similar error from nasm when I change the `mov` instructions for `lea`. The error is `error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses`

How do I resolve these errors?

In the code below any instruction after `mov rcx, msg1` (including nops, other `mov` instructions or just anythging) will cause LD to throw the above error. I have used a call instruction in this instance but any instruction will cause this error.

The later `mov` instruction (`mov rax, 0x2000001`) does not seem to cause the issue. As such if the call instruction is commented out and everything else left the same LD will not throw an error.

```
bits 64

section .text
    global  _main                               ;must be declared for linker (ld)
    global  _print

_print:
    mov     rbx, 1                              ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov     rax, 0x4                            ;system call number (sys_write)
    bts     rax, 25
    syscall
    ret

_main:
    mov     rdx, len1
    mov     rcx, msg1
    call    _print                              ;will not compile if this is not commented out

    ; <any instruction between mov rcx, msg1 and mov rax, 0x2000001
    ; causes LD to throw a pointer misalignment error
    ; ld: warning: pointer not aligned at address 0x100003FA3 (_main + 7 from print.o)
    ; ld: unaligned pointer(s) for architecture x86_64

    mov   rax, 0x2000001                ; system call 0x1 with 0x2000000 offset
    mov   rbx, 0x0                  ; set the exit code to be 0x0
    syscall

section .data
    msg1    db 'here 1', 0xa
    len1    equ $ - msg1
    msg2    db 'here 2', 0xa
    len2    equ $ - msg2
    msg3    db 'here 3', 0xa
    len3    equ $ - msg3
    msg4    db 'here 4', 0xa
    len4    equ $ - msg4
    msg5    db 'here 5', 0xa
    len5    equ $ - msg5
```

NASM command: `nasm -f macho64 print.asm`.
ld command: `ld -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem print.o -o print`

Follow up:

In the end the following code worked as intended and printed the string to std out:

```
bits 64

default rel

section .text
    global  _main                               ;must be declared for linker (ld)
    global  _print

_print:
    mov     rdi, 1                              ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov     rax, 0x4                            ;system call number (sys_write)
    bts     rax, 25
    syscall
    ret

_main:
    lea     rsi, [rel msg1]
    lea     rdx, [rel len1]
    call    _print

    nop
    nop
    nop

    mov   rax, 0x2000001                ; system call 0x1 with 0x2000000 offset
  mov   rbx, 0x0                    ; set the exit code to be 0x0
  syscall

section .data
    msg1    db 'here 1', 0xa
    len1    equ $ - msg1
    msg2    db 'here 2', 0xa
    len2    equ $ - msg2
    msg3    db 'here 3', 0xa
    len3    equ $ - msg3
    msg4    db 'here 4', 0xa
    len4    equ $ - msg4
    msg5    db 'here 5', 0xa
    len5    equ $ - msg5
```

When I run `objdump -dx print` I get an error stating:

```
print:  file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: error: 'print': Invalid/Unsupported object file format
```

However when I run `objdump -d print` I get:

```
print:  file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000100003f83 <_print>:
100003f83: bf 01 00 00 00               movl    $1, %edi
100003f88: b8 04 00 00 00               movl    $4, %eax
100003f8d: 48 0f ba e8 19               btsq    $25, %rax
100003f92: 0f 05                        syscall
100003f94: c3                           retq

0000000100003f95 <_main>:
100003f95: 48 8d 35 64 00 00 00         leaq    100(%rip), %rsi         ## 0x100004000 <msg1>
100003f9c: 48 8d 14 25 07 00 00 00      leaq    7, %rdx
100003fa4: e8 da ff ff ff               callq   0x100003f83 <_print>
100003fa9: 90                           nop
100003faa: 90                           nop
100003fab: 90                           nop
100003fac: b8 01 00 00 02               movl    $33554433, %eax         ## imm = 0x2000001
100003fb1: bb 00 00 00 00               movl    $0, %ebx
100003fb6: 0f 05                        syscall
```

Adding `otool -dtvr print.o` output:

```
% otool -dtvr print.o      
test.o:
Relocation information (__TEXT,__text) 1 entries
address  pcrel length extern type    scattered symbolnum/value
0000000f False quad   True   UNSIGND False     msg1
(__TEXT,__text) section
_print:
0000000000000000    movl    $0x1, %edi
0000000000000005    movl    $0x2000004, %eax                ## imm = 0x2000004
000000000000000a    syscall
000000000000000c    retq
_main:
000000000000000d    movabsq $0x0, %rsi
0000000000000017    movl    $0x7, %edx
000000000000001c    callq   0x0
0000000000000021    movl    $0x2000001, %eax                ## imm = 0x2000001
0000000000000026    movl    $0x0, %ebx
000000000000002b    syscall
(__DATA,__data) section
000000000000002d    68 65 72 65 20 31 0a 68 65 72 65 20 32 0a 68 65 
000000000000003d    72 65 20 33 0a 68 65 72 65 20 34 0a 68 65 72 65 
000000000000004d    20 35 0a
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it was a shot in the dark, and I don't see anything peculiar. I'm almost wondering if there is some bizarre issue with your Apple SDK or something. It is very perplexing. I'm really surprised that objdump gives the error it does on a Macho64 object as well.That extra padding of NOPs is not necessary under normal circumstances, something is very wrong IMHO. I wonder if there is a conflict between tools in Brew and the Appls SDK causing this. I'm at a loss to explain it.